# GTK gtkdialog window to make a link

Tags: shell-script, gnome, gtk

[image]

I'm trying to make a pop-up window that lets you select a directory. In the background, this will make a link to that directory. I'm using bash scripting and gtkdialog.

For example:

```
/home/rich/movies --> /home/rich/content/movies/hd/
```

Comment: Concerning the link you would use `mount --bind`.

Comment: im using a bash script to make the link . but i want to be able to replace /change the link with gtkdialog window . i just need a window to pop up and iselect the dir and it makes the link